# In React, how do I properly use hooks to update one component when I trigger an Add function in another component?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-hooks, react-component

I am building an app for finding books in order to learn React. I cannot figure out how to add a book from my list of *all* books ("Book List") into a separate "Reading List". I have a JSON data file of books that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "descr": "Take a voyeuristic look at life in Sheffield...",
    "author": "Philip Hensher",
    "title_id": "9812",
    "title": "The Northern Clemency",
    "cover": "https://www.whichbook.net/assets/images/big/9812.jpg",
    "similar": "https://www.whichbook.net/#cmd=search&search-type=3&id=9812"
  },
  ...
]
```

and I loop through them in my BookList.js component to display each book and a button to "Add to Reading List" like so:

```
export default function BookList ({ handleAddBook }) {
    return (
        <div>
            {BookData.map((book) => {
                return (
                <>
                    <BookDetail key={book.title_id} book={book} />
                    <button onClick={handleAddBook}>Add to Reading List</button>
                </>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

For each BookDetail, I simply display the title and title_id. In BookDetail.js:

```
export default function BookDetail({ book }) {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{book.title}</h1>
            <p>{book.title_id}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This works great. I see a list of all my books. Now, in my ReadingList.js I attempt to loop through books similar to my BookList, except the functional component has a `booksToRead` argument:

```
export default function ReadingList({ booksToRead }) {
    return (
        <div>
            <h3>My Reading List</h3>
            {booksToRead.map((book) => {
                return (
                <>
                    <BookDetail key={book.title_id} book={book} />
                </>
                )
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Ok, so now let's look at App.js where I have attempted to work this out. Basically I am trying to use `useState()` and `useEffect()` to update my `booksToRead` array whenever the constant `newBookToRead` changes, which is handled in the `handleAddBook` function. I initialized `booksToRead` with dummy data, and it displays in the browser, but never updates.

```
function App() {

    const [books, setBooks] = useState([])
    const [booksToRead, setBooksToRead] = useState([{ title: 'initialBookToRead', title_id: '1234' }])
    const [newBookToRead, setNewBookToRead] = useState([{ title: 'addMe', title_id: '000' }])

    function handleAddBook() {
        setNewBookToRead(newBookToRead)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setBooksToRead(booksToRead => [...booksToRead, newBookToRead])
    }, [newBookToRead])


  return (
    <main>
        <BookList books={books} />
        <ReadingList booksToRead={booksToRead} />
    </main>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I've tried moving the logic around to the different components, I've tried creating a ReadingListContext with `createContext` and using `ReadingListContext.Provider value={booksToRead}` instead of the `<ReadingList>` tag, I just can't figure it out.

Also, potentially unrelated, my console gives me `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.` for both `BookList` and `ReadingList`, even though I set the key to `book.title_id` which is a unique code. ????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export default function BookList ({ books, handleAddBook }) {
return (
    <div>
        {books.map((book) => {
            const onAddBook = () => handleAddBook(book);
            return (
            <>
                <BookDetail key={book.title_id} book={book} />
                <button onClick={onAddBook}>Add to Reading List</button>
            </>
            )
        })}
    </div>
)
}

function App() {

    const [books, setBooks] = useState([])
    const [booksToRead, setBooksToRead] = useState([{ title: 'initialBookToRead', title_id: '1234' }])

    function handleAddBook(book) {
        setBooksToRead([...booksToRead, book])
    }


  return (
    <main>
        <BookList books={books} handleAddBook={handleAddBook}/>
        <ReadingList booksToRead={booksToRead} />
    </main>
  );

}

export default App;
```

Please use above components. You need to pass book as param to handleAddBook. No need to store newBookToRead and useEffect you can use handleAddBook as mentioned.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much.